# How do i make show/hide password

Tags: c#

I've been doing this function, and i would like to ask, whats the problem behind this one? I Made if statement, and nothing happens, the chad doesn't change, i tried to make Application.Exit on the if function, and the app exited. I wanna to make that Show Password/Hide Password function on MetroTextBox

```
if (metroTextBox1.PasswordChar == '●')
{
    metroTextBox1.PasswordChar = '\0';//
}
else
{
    metroTextBox1.PasswordChar = '●';
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you showed us checks if the character is a dot, and if true, sets it to the same thing. Have you tried the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property?

Comment: How do i need to use this function UseSystemPasswordChar, i need to make that the password dot in textbox, switch to text.

Comment: So you want the text box to toggle between a dot and plain text? How does your current code work differently? I get the desired toggle result from copy/pasting your code.

Comment: Yes, in the textbox, should change passwordchar from dot to plain text

Comment: How does your current code work differently? I get the desired toggle result from copy/pasting your code.

Comment: My code should change the passwordchar from dot to plain text, but that doesn't work

Comment: What I am asking is what doesn't work? Does pressing the button do nothing? does the code you posted not execute? Is it affecting the wrong textbox? There's some other mysterious factor at work here causing it to not work, because the code you provided does, in fact, work.

Comment: The dot doesn't change to plain text

Comment: Debug your code a bit more to find out _why_ the dot doesn't change to plain text. Everything provided thus far produces the expected result. Toggling back and forth between dots and plain text.

Comment: Can you make the code yourself, and share here?

Comment: I literally copy/pasted the code you posted, put only that inside a button click event handler, and it worked. No other code at all besides what is generated when the form is created. I have only a textbox and a button on the form. None of the properties were changed after dragging them onto the form. What you provided works. What you _didn't_ provide, is what I assume isn't working.

Comment: I made a gif https://gyazo.com/e52cfae3800af9d4f72bd374677e3a3f

Comment: So yes, something else is causing you're problem. Try creating a new, clean project, and start copying your current code into this throw-away project. You can start removing pieces in order to isolate the issue, this alone may lead you to your answer. As it stands, there's not enough info for me to help you, as the code in your question works as intended. If you discover which bit of code is the culprit and are not sure how to fix it, include that part in the question.

Comment: @St.Pat Fair enough, removing, OP: by any chance, do you have more than 1 metroTextBox in your form? Maybe you're targeting the wrong one

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna to make that Show Password/Hide Password function on
>   MetroTextBox

```
void showPassword(TextBox textBox, bool show)
{
    if(show)
        textBox.PasswordChar = '\0';
    else
        textBox.PasswordChar = '*';
}
```

Now, anytime you want to show the password, call it like this:

```
showPassword(metroTextBox1, true);
```

Hide the password:

```
showPassword(metroTextBox1, false);
```

You can call this from a toggle box.

Comment: What I see is a compile error. Are you sure you declared `metroTextBox1`? All you need to pass there is an instance of your `TextBox`. It doesn't have to be named `metroTextBox1`

Comment: @user9745220 Is `metroTextBox1` **not** a TextBox? If it's a custom control, just change the parameter `TextBox textBox` of `showPassword` to the type of your `metroTextBox1`. Also, Casey's answer is using the parameter `textBox` to assign the `PasswordChar` property, you're calling a specific control inside the method (bad practice), don't change the method posted in the answer.

Comment: So what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Use the text changed method of your textbox and to capture new inputs froms the user and validate if the key pressed corresponds to a printable character. You can apend this to a local variable and clear the text field, this way you capture the password while keeping the field empty. I think this is the idea you have

Comment: The `PasswordChar` property used in the question does the hiding for you, so this kind of manual management isn't necessary. There's something else preventing OP's code from working.

Comment: It is important to also note if the method is called in a event that is recursive. This would create an infinite loop when the char is continously toggled back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add button_Click ? Double click on the button ,and it will be automatically created, then you just have to paste your code!

Sorry if i was bad, but it's working fine for me!